# Do I need an Add-in or a Stand-Alone Application for a custom form?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, c#

The type of application I want to build for ArcMap is to be run from inside of ArcMap and on a click of a button a custom form appears in front of User in which User enters certain parameters and then by some processing, the application returns resulting image to user in the same ArcMap Document...
So will this application be an Add-in or Stand-Alone Application..??

Comment: In terms of returning an image to your user, would this image be a raster added to the Table of Contents? Or would it be an image that is just for information and to add something to your print out?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding...
actually I want to return a new dataframe into the same ArcMap document with new shape files to user...

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you developing for?

Comment: Sorry for this late reply...

@blah238 I am developing for ArcMap 10.0

Comment: Do you want to add a new shape file in the current map?

Answer (score 7):

Custom forms can only be created with [ESRI Add-ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001ms000000). I believe you can also create custom forms in 10.1 with [Python (ArcPy) Add-Ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/)

Although if all your user needs to do is select certain parameters, you can probably accomplish this with a python script. You can then add that script to a toolbox and set the parameters there: [ArcGIS Documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/)

As for having a button that launches the form, you can accomplish this by customizing your interface and selecting your newly created python script.

The last part specifies that you want an image to return to the user, I'll edit this once you specify if the image is a raster (which would be added to the TOC) or an image that will be added to your layout.

Comment: actually I am doing the programming with C# and I don't have any Python knowledge...


as for output is considered...
Sorry for the misunderstanding...
actually I want to return a new dataframe into the same ArcMap document with new shape files to user...

Comment: No problem, I don't know C#, so hopefully someone will come along with a C# answer for you soon!

Comment: "Custom forms can only be created with ESRI Add-in's" this isn't exactly true. Add-ins were introduced at 10.0 and people were definitely creating forms before that. :) See [What you can do: Developing against ArcGIS Desktop (9.3)](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/shared/desktop/get_started/what_develop_dtop.htm)